# Difficulties of implementing function in Julia involving if, else and matrices

Tags: julia, juno-ide

I am trying to implement this function in Julia and I am not getting it. I think it's because of broadcasting, it doesn't seem to work with arrays.
When I write the relational operators with dot (like .> instead of >), the number of errors decreases, but it accuses "TypeError: non-boolean (BitVector) used in boolean context".
How can I fix this?

```
function Rulkov(N, X, Y, α)
    global σ, μ
    for n=1:1:N
    if (X[n, 1]<=0)
        X[n, 2]  = α[n] / (1 - X[n, 1])  + Y[n, 1]

    elseif (X[n, 1]>0 && X[n, 1]<(α .+ Y[n, 1]))
        X[n, 2]  = α[n] + Y[n, 1]
    else
        X[n, 2]  = -1
    end
    
    Y[n, 2]  = Y[n, 1]  - μ*(X[n, 1] .+ 1) .+ μ*σ

    end
    return sum(X[:, 2])/N
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that `X` and `Y` are matrices, `X[n, 1]` is a scalar and `α .+ Y[n, 1]` is a `Vector`, so there is no meaningful comparison between these objects. So, depending on what you want you can either use

```
all(X[n, 1] .< (α .+ Y[n, 1])))
```

or (probably more correct from the mathematical point of view)

```
X[n, 1] < minimum(α .+ Y[n, 1])
```

or non-allocating version of the previous calculation

```
X[n, 1] < minimum(x -> x + Y[n, 1], α)
```

or (as it was proposed in comments)

```
X[n, 1] < minimum(α) + Y[n, 1]
```

Comment: Or `minimum(α) + Y[n, 1]`?

Comment: Ha, you are right, overengineering on my side :-)

Comment: Wow! I did not know these functions! The proposal to use the "all" function I understood, but I still don't understand what the minimum function does. Anyway, I used all and it worked really well! I am very satisfied! Thank you so much!

Comment: The `minimum` function finds the minimum value in a collection. Apt name, really.

Answer (score 2):

`if`, `else` only accepts a boolean. So I guess you need to call `all` or `any` on the `BitVector` first?